# OOP PHP with FB Graph API

Tags: php, oop, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Student object using OOP in PHP via the Facebook Graph API. My problem is that not all users share the same amount of data on FB so if a particular user doesn't list certain variables instantiated in the object, I get undefined variable messages. What is the best way to prepare for this, i.e. create an object whether or not the user has shared all of the data in the object or not? Code below:

```
<?php
require_once('class.Student.php');

$name = $user_profile['name'];
$hometown = $user_profile['hometown']['name'];
$location = $user_profile['location']['name'];
$birthday = $user_profile['birthday'];
$highschool = $user_profile['education'][0]['school']['name'];
$hsgrad = $user_profile['education'][0]['year']['name'];
$collegeid = $user_profile['education'][1]['school']['id'];
$college = $user_profile['education'][1]['school']['name'];
$majorid = $user_profile['education'][1]['concentration'][0]['id'];
$major = $user_profile['education'][1]['concentration'][0]['name'];
$grad = $user_profile['education'][1]['year']['name'];
$company = $user_profile['work'][0]['employer']['name'];
$jobtitle = $user_profile['work'][0]['position']['name'];
$startdate = $user_profile['work'][0]['start_date'];
$interest = $interests['data'][0]['name'];
$interestid = $interests['data'][0]['id'];

$objStudent = new Student($name,$hometown,$location,$birthday,$highschool,$hsgrad,$collegeid,$college,$majorid,$major,$grad,$company,$jobtitle,$startdate,$interest,$interestid);   

?>
```

And the class itself:

```
<?php

class Student {

public $name;
public $hometown;
public $location;
public $birthday;
public $highschool;
public $hsgrad;
public $collegeid;
public $college;
public $majorid;
public $major;
public $grad;
public $company;
public $jobtitle;
public $startdate;
public $interest;
public $interestid;


    public function __construct($name,$hometown,$location,$birthday,$highschool,$hsgrad,$collegeid,$college,$majorid,$major,$grad,$company,$jobtitle,$startdate,$interest,$interestid) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->hometown = $hometown;
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->birthday = $birthday;
        $this->highschool = $highschool;
        $this->hsgrad = $hsgrad;
        $this->collegeid = $collegeid;
        $this->college = $college;
        $this->majorid = $majorid;
        $this->major = $major;
        $this->grad = $grad;
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->jobtitle = $jobtitle;
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
        $this->interest = $interest;
        $this->interestid = $interestid;
    }
```

I understand how to handle this in the functions of the class, using a simple isset such as:

```
  function goalRecommender () {

        if (isset($this->interest)) {
            if ($this->interest =='Computer Science') {
            echo "<p>Based on your interest in Computer Science, we recommend working in the software industry. Furthermore, your interest in user interface design would be thoroughly put to use at Facebook, one of the fastest growing technology companies in the world. If you would like to pursue another goal,
            search our database to the right or click one of the 'popular goal' links.<p>";
            }
            elseif ($this->interests =='Finance') {
                echo "<p>You're interested in Finance</p>";
            }
            elseif ($this->interests =='Film') {
                echo "<p>You're interested in Film</p>";
        }
            elseif ($this->interests =='Marketing') {
                echo "<p>You're interested in Marketing</p>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Choose a goal.</p>";
            }
        }   else  {
                echo "<p>What are you interested in?
                <select>
                <option>Finance</option>
                <option>Marketing</option>
                <option>Film</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                </select></p>";
        }
    }
```

But I'm just learning OOP in PHP and am unsure how to do it when instantiating an object. Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**There's a lot for your class:**

- **Have your Student constructor take an array.** This will reduce the pain of variable adjustments, especially if you end up extending `Student`.**Clarification:** rather than passing in the name, college, hometown, birthday, etc, you pass in an array that has all that same information.

  ```
  $name = $user_profile['name'];
  $hometown = $user_profile['hometown']['name'];

  //becomes

  $user['name'] = $user_profile['name'];
  $user['hometown'] = $user_profile['hometown']['name'];
  ```

  - **It's faster.**  The cost of any parameter isn't much, but when you have tons like this it can at least make a mark.
  - **It's easier to call.** You no longer have to remember the order of variables.  "Is it name, hometown, location, birthday? Or name, birthday, location, hometown?"  You have tons of variables, there's no way to easily remember that.
  - **It's easier to change.**  Adding a variable?  No problem, add it to the array and check for it inside the function.  Removing a variable? That's hard to do, but not if it's in an array.

    ```
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $hometown,
        $location,
        $birthday,
        $highschool,
        $hsgrad,
        $collegeid,
        $college,
        $majorid,
        $major,
        $grad,
        $company,
        $jobtitle,
        $startdate,
        $interest,
        $interestid) {

    //becomes
    public function __construct(array $info) {
    ```
- **Your variables should be `protected` or `private`, not `public`.** This is pretty much industry standard.

  - **You'll want to provide getter and setter methods** because the variables are inaccessible.  Many IDE's can do this for you.

**As for your error messages:**

- **You need to check to make sure the variable exists before you actually access it.**  Use the `isset()` function for this:

  ```
  $hometown = isset($user_profile['hometown']['name']) ? $user_profile['hometown']['name'] : null;
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I've implemented 2/3 of your suggestions. The first one: "Have your constructor take an array" I'm a bit unclear on. I think you're referring to the Graph when you mention variable adjustments. Like, if a user only has college listed, there will be a [0] for college but if they list hs and college, college is the [1] outset. If so, how do I have the constructor take an array to solve this, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @MattMcClintock I updated the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: When you wrote construct (array $info) did you mean construct (array $user)?

Comment: @MattMcClintock It doesn't really matter what you name the array.  But that's the idea, yes.

Comment: So what goes after the constructor? public function __construct(array $user) { ??????? }